# drop-down-menu goes to three lines.

Tags: html, css

I have developed a drop-down-menu but the  it goes to three lines. The top item links are covered by the main items on lines two and three so I cannot see the first two links underneath the items on the top line.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please post minimal code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please add some codes or  a snippet.

Comment: Thanks so much Mujthaba.

Comment: I could not fit the CSS and HTML on this space. It did not allow me so I have put it on my blog temporarily. You can find it all here
https://dallymessenger.com/2017/06/30/drop-down-menu/

Comment: Here it is unfinished on the internet.
http://www.collegeofcelebrancy.com